# Actors and extending use cases in UML

Tags: uml, use-case

If an actor communicates with use case A, does he automatically communicate with an extending use case B or do I have to draw a second association beetween the actor and use case B - if my intention is to have the actor execute both A and B? What if, instead of <<`extends`>>, the the association between A and B was <<`includes`>>? Would a line between the actor and use case A also imply that the actor can execute the included use case (B)? Or do I have to draw a second line from the actor to use case b?

---

EDIT: I'm afraid I did not make myself clear. My doubt is not about the semantics of *includes* and *extends* or when use them, but rather their correct representation on a diagram. If I was asked to draw an ATM use case diagram, I'd probably would come up with the same diagram @RedBeard presented. However, in the site [http://elearning.uml.ac.at/], they assert that, acording to them UML2 standard, for the diagram to be complete, one should also draw two more associations, connecting the actor directly to the included and extending use cases, that is, one line from the actor to `Card Identification` and one more from the actor to `Online Help`, otherwise these use cases would never be executed. Since I found this explanation nowhere in the UML Super Strucure book, I decided to post this question here.

Answer (score 0):

I add an example coming (more or less) from UML2.5 Specifiation. As you can see when a "*Customer*" want to "*Withdraw*" he must "*Card Identication*" because you have an *Include* from "*Withdraw*" to "*Card Identication*" so a "*Card Identication*" **is always included** when a "*Customer*" want to "*Withdraw*".

At the same time when a "*Customer*" want to "*Perform ATM Transaction*" (which can be a "*Withdraw*", a "*Transfer*", or a "*Deposit*"), he **may, or not** select a "*On line Help*". Thsi is due to the *Extend* link between  "*Perform ATM Transaction*" and "*On line Help*" which means that a "*Perform ATM Transaction*" **can be extended by** "*On line Help*".

So if you want to model the fact that a actor have to do **always both A and B** an *Include* link would work. An *Include* link model a **possible** extension which is not mandatory. Hoping it is clear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Red Beard. Please see my edit to the original question.

Comment: For me you do not need more association....
I could understand these additional association but I am not that the UML idea here...